# How to run Gitlab $dependabot rebase

Tags: gitlab

I'm using Gitlab [dependabot](https://gitlab.com/dependabot-gitlab/dependabot) and it creates merge requests when there are some changes in the packages. It works fine but when I merge one MR the other one is outdated so it needs to be rebeased.

It gives me this output

> You can trigger Dependabot actions by commenting on this MR. `$dependabot rebase` will rebase this MR. `$dependabot recreate` will recreate this MR rewriting all the manual changes and resolving conflicts.

I thought I could use this command directly in the comment but when I try to comment it like `$dependabot rebase` or `/$dependabot rebase`
it comments like a regular text.

Can I run this command via the MR comment area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [GitHub PR](https://github.com/Maxim-Mazurok/google-api-typings-generator/pull/441#issuecomment-778716301=) (same idea for GitLab MR) shows a comment with:

```
@dependabot rebase
```

There is no '`$`'